# Rotating after an animation

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UIViewController subclass that can display animations (mostly changing alphas on imageview subviews). If an animation is occurring when the device is rotated, I would like the rotation animation to occur after the current animation block completes. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a method that animated an image, set some BOOLean value to NO and conditionally allow rotation in the `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method.  Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (!someBool)
        return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: That's where I was stuck. This prevents the rotation during the animation -- to get it to possibly rotate afterwards it looks like I need to call "attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation". I should also add code to prevent animations from occurring during the animation itself.